# Scipy Maximization Issue

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have been struggling with scipy to maximize the function `2x^(1/2)+4x^(1/2)` st `(1/4)x+y=4` however I could not figure out if there is any option to toggle minimization to maximization. I would really appreciate any help. Below is what I was trying to do but I am not getting any output:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import optimization

fun = lambda x: 2*x[0]**(0.5)+4*x[1]**(0.5)
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  0.25*x[0] +  x[1] - 4})
bnds = ((0, None), (0, None))
res = minimize(fun, (2, 0), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

Comment: minimum(f) = -maximum(f)

Comment: in any case I am not getting any output. Am I using the correct steps?

Comment: I think you mean `minimum(f) = -maximum(-f)`